# Can you update device contact lists when using Hybrid Remote?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Hi according to the documentation, Hybrid approach has device access to contacts. But can you update contacts in the hybrid VF approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial for this below

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK

One thing you would have observed is that SDK comes with cordova library and hence it was easy to implement .

Use the same principle for visualforce as well .

> Import the Cordova library in the static resource in the Visualforce

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Cordova}"/>
```

Once you import you can use JS function to access contact info

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

NOTE:::: Please note adding Cordova is not supported if your page needs to work inside SF1 mobile app .